# pandas get duplicate level for each duplicate entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like

```
    type   val greet
0   foo    0   hi
1   foo    1   hello
2   foo    1   bye
3   bar    1   come
4   foo    0   go
5   foo    0   no
```

I want to find duplicates based on type and val (both together)
like type=foo and val=0 is duplicated 3 times
But I need to get duplicate instance value as well like

```
    type   val greet  instance
0   foo    0   hi     1
1   foo    1   hello  1
2   foo    1   bye    2
3   bar    1   come   1
4   foo    0   go     2
5   foo    0   no     3
```

Tried `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['type', 'val'], keep=first)` but this is not the correct way to approach.
Also read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html)
I think it will be done using `groupby` but adding instance count is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `'type'` and `'val'`, apply `cumcount` and add one.

```
>>> df['instance'] = df.groupby(['type', 'val']).cumcount() + 1
>>> df
  type  val  greet  instance
0  foo    0     hi         1
1  foo    1  hello         1
2  foo    1    bye         2
3  bar    1   come         1
4  foo    0     go         2
5  foo    0     no         3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick ans